# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" - Después de una edición mi código ya no funciona

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de codificar el juego de la serpiente en python, todo estaba bien hasta que el cuerpo no seguía a la cabeza...

```
cuerpo1 = []

while True:
    s.update()
    if snake.xcor() > 300 or snake.xcor() < -380 or snake.ycor() > 325 or snake.ycor() < -325:
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in cuerpo1:
            i.clear()
            i.hideturtle()
        snake.home()
        snake.direction = "stop"
        cuerpo1.clear()

        marcador = 0
        texto.clear()
        texto.write("Score: {}\tRecord: {}".format(marcador,marcador_alto),align="center",font=("consolas",20,"normal")

    if snake.distance(comida) < 20:
        x = random.randint(-375,375)
        y = random.randint(-325,325)
        comida.goto(x,y)
        cuerpo = turtle.Turtle()
        cuerpo.shape("square")
        cuerpo.color("yellow")
        cuerpo.penup()
        cuerpo.speed(0)
        cuerpo1.append(cuerpo)
        marcador += 10
        if marcador > marcador_alto:
            marcador_alto = marcador
            texto.clear()
            texto.write("Score: {}\tRecord: {}".format(marcador,marcador_alto),align="center",font=("consolas",20,"normal")

    total = len(cuerpo1)
    for index in range(-1,0,-1):
        x = cuerpo1[index-1].xcor()
        y = cuerpo1[index-1].ycor()
        cuerpo1[index].goto(x,y)

    if  len(cuerpo1) > 0 :
        x = snake.xcor()
        y = snake.ycor()
        cuerpo1[0].goto(x,y)

    moves()

    for index in cuerpo1:
        if index.distance(snake) < 20 :
            for i in cuerpo1:
                i.clear()
                i.hideturtle()
            cuerpo1.clear()
            snake.direction = "stop"
    time.sleep(retraso)

turtle.done()
```

Ahora, me marca error de sintaxis en los condicionales...
alguien que me ayude a identificar el error o me ayude a resolverlo ya que ahora al intentar ejecutar el programa, ya no me deja arrancar el juego y solo me marca error de sintaxis en los dos puntos de todas las condicionales y por ende, en las variables que declare en los mismos condicionales

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error específico que te arroja el intérprete de Python?

Comment: if snake.distance(comida) < 20:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

eso me marca

Comment: Te falta cerrar un paréntesis en la línea anterior, la del `write`

Comment: Hola Carlos, te sugiero que cambies el titulo de la pregunta a algo más descriptivo. Piensa que StackOverflow es para la comunidad, y que otra persona en el futuro puede tener tu mismo problema y con "COMO REPARAR EL CODIGO" no le ayudará a encontrar la solución. Te sugiero un nombre como el texto del error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" o algo que tu pienses que describe el fallo, no lo que quieres que haga tu programa. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Te comistes un ")" antes del `if`

```
    texto.write("Score: {}\tRecord: {}".format(marcador,marcador_alto),align="center",font=("consolas",20,"normal"))

if snake.distance(comida) < 20:
```

Lo mismo que aqui:

```
        texto.write("Score: {}\tRecord: {}".format(marcador,marcador_alto),align="center",font=("consolas",20,"normal"))

total = len(cuerpo1)
```

Y tampoco existe la variable `s` en

```
s.update()
```

¿Será `snake`?